# How can I make the performance O(N) instead of O(N^2)?

Tags: objective-c, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to understand how to make the time complexity better for this problem:

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   The consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive cars on a
>   road.
>
> Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s: 0 represents a car traveling east, 1 represents a car traveling west.
>
> The goal is to count passing cars. We say that a pair of cars (P, Q),
>   where 0 ≤ P < Q < N, is passing when P is traveling to the east and Q
>   is traveling to the west.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 0   
> A[1] = 1   
> A[2] = 0   
> A[3] = 1   
> A[4] = 1
> ```
>
> We have five pairs of passing cars: (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4).
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> int solution(NSMutableArray *A);
> ```
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns
>   the number of pairs of passing cars.
>
> The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing cars
>   exceeds 1,000,000,000.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
>
> Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments). Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

Solution:

```
   int solution(NSMutableArray *A) {
// write your code in Objective-C 2.0

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < A.count; i++) {
    if ([A[i] intValue] == 0) {
        for (int j = i; j < A.count; j++) {
            if ([A[j] intValue] == 1) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}


return counter;
}
```

Right now the solution is running at O(N^2) due to the nested for loops. I cant seem to wrap my head around how to solve it in O(N) time. This isn't homework; I'm just refreshing algorithms for interviews.

Comment: have another value, call it `inc/increment` and initialize it as 0. increment that value at every occurrence of 0 and increment counter at every occurrence of 1.

Comment: this works because as you are going through your list, you know that every time you hit a 0, every value of 1 AFTER that will create a passing pair. So at every 0, every 1 after that will create one more pair since there is a passing pair for each 0 that you already encountered

Comment: Now, when I am reading your comment, I know how I should name that variable, great catch, @RNar!

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a programming task from a website that might be used for job interview tests, for example. The giveaway is the use of NSMutableArray which means you are looking for an iOS job. The problem itself is one of those where the solution should be obvious once you know it's possible.

Comment: @gnasher729: OP says as much in the last sentence: "...I'm just refreshing algorithms for interviews."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
NSInteger solutionCountingDifferentDirections(NSMutableArray *A) {
    NSInteger multiplier = 1;
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    NSInteger firstCarDirection = A[0];
    for (NSInteger idx = 1; idx < A.count; idx++) {
        if (firstCarDirection == A[idx]) {
            multiplier++;
        }
        else {
            counter += multiplier;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

**EDIT:**
@RNar suggested that we don't count first cars with west direction so here's solution for that case:

```
NSInteger solutionCountingFromFirstEastDirection(NSMutableArray *A) {
    NSInteger multiplier = 0;
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    for (NSInteger idx = 0; idx < A.count; idx++) {
        if (A[idx] == 0) {
            multiplier++;
        }
        else {
            counter += multiplier;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I think that it doesn't matter what the first car is, the program seems to just want the pairs if a car travelling east and passing a car travelling west so, as much as the add-on is cool, it is unnecessary?

Comment: @RNar, These requirements are not 100% clear for me. I thought that we need to count cars traveling in different directions, that's why I need first direction to check with. Do you trying to say that if few first items are cars traveling west (1) we need to just skip them and only count from first east-directioned car?

Comment: yeah, thats what the problem definition seems to say.

Comment: change your start index for the second one to 0 not 1 since you now need to read in the first car

Comment: "Passing" is indeed defined as A[P] == 0 && A[Q] == 1 && P < Q. Seems like a strange definition; A[P] != A[Q] would make more sense to me as well.

Comment: None of these solutions seem to work... I think the question may be confusing (usually thats the goal)...

Basically for every 0 in the array you want to count the number of 1's after it.

EX: [0,1,1,0,1] = 
first 0 has 3 ones after it. First pass = 3
second 0 has 1 one after it. Second pass = 1 + 3 = 4

Comment: @RNar , great catch!
JeremySh , second version is doing exactly what you described. For each previously encountered 0 we add 1 successful "passing"